# GEF sketchy figure

Tags: eclipse-gef

I am trying to create a eclipse based editor for class diagram for a school project. One of the main requirement is that the diagram need to have a "sketchy effect" (something like the one shown in this website [yuml](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/samples))

I am new to Eclipse graphical editor frameworks, and I want to get some opinion about how I can implement it (pros/cons of using plain GEF vs GMF). My preference will be to use GEF as it may require a lot of customization in the future and I find that GMF has a high learning curve and not much documentation.

If I implement it using GEF, will it better done by using SVG graphics and should the figure or edit parts be splitted (to three parts : box for Class name, box for Properties, and box for Methods)?

Answer (score 0):

Think it's best to use SVG for the sketchy shape. GEF doesn't have support for SVG images, GMF does. You can try to borrow SVG handling from GMF - it's not too complicated.
Properties and methods should be text labels figures and children of properties and method compartment figures that are nested inside the class shape. See this: https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-Draw2d/GEF-Draw2d.html